# How to increase speed of large for loops

Tags: multithreading, openmp, ros

Right now i'm trying to run very large for loops for some task, nearly about 8e+12 iterations. I tried using c++11 threading, but it do not seems to be working that fast as required. I am using system with 8 gb ram, i5 cpu and intel graphics 4000 card. If i use openmp would it be better or i have to use nvidia gpu and use cuda for this task? My code is as below:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
// PCL specific includes
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>
#include <visualization_msgs/Marker.h>
#include <rosbag/bag.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int32.h>
#include <rosbag/view.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#define foreach BOOST_FOREACH
#include <fstream>

#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/octree/octree_pointcloud_changedetector.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <thread>
ros::Publisher marker_publisher;
int frame_index = 0;
using namespace std;
int x[200000];
void thread_function(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr cloudB,vector<int> v,int p0) {
    for(size_t p1=0;p1<v.size() && ros::ok();++p1) {
        int p0p1 = sqrt( pow(cloudB->points[v[p1]].x-cloudB->points[v[p0]].x,2)                
        +pow(cloudB->points[v[p1]].y-cloudB->points[v[p0]].y,2)
        +pow(cloudB->points[v[p1]].z-cloudB->points[v[p0]].z,2) ) * 1000;
        if(p0p1>10) {
            for(size_t p2=0;p2<v.size() && ros::ok();++p2) {
                int p0p2 = sqrt( pow(cloudB->points[v[p2]].x-cloudB->points[v[p0]].x,2)                
                +pow(cloudB->points[v[p2]].y-cloudB->points[v[p0]].y,2)
                +pow(cloudB->points[v[p2]].z-cloudB->points[v[p0]].z,2) ) * 1000;
                int p1p2 = sqrt( pow(cloudB->points[v[p2]].x-cloudB->points[v[p1]].x,2)                
                +pow(cloudB->points[v[p2]].y-cloudB->points[v[p1]].y,2)
                +pow(cloudB->points[v[p2]].z-cloudB->points[v[p1]].z,2) ) * 1000;
                if(p0p2>10 && p1p2>10) {
                }    
            }    
        }       
    }    
    x[p0] = 3;
    cout<<"ended thread="<<p0<<endl;
}

void cloud_cb (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
{
    frame_index++;
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloudB (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> );
    pcl::fromROSMsg(*input,*cloudB);

    // Initializing Marker parameters which will be used in rviz
    vector<visualization_msgs::Marker> line_list, marker, text_view_facing;
    line_list.resize(4); marker.resize(4); text_view_facing.resize(4);
    for(int i=0;i<line_list.size();i++) {
        marker[i].header.frame_id = line_list[i].header.frame_id = text_view_facing[i].header.frame_id = "/X3/base_link";
        marker[i].header.stamp = line_list[i].header.stamp = text_view_facing[i].header.stamp =ros::Time();
        marker[i].ns = line_list[i].ns = text_view_facing[i].ns ="lines";
        marker[i].action = line_list[i].action = text_view_facing[i].action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
        marker[i].pose.orientation.w = line_list[i].pose.orientation.w = text_view_facing[i].pose.orientation.w = 1;
        marker[i].id = i+4;
        line_list[i].id = i;
        marker[i].type = visualization_msgs::Marker::POINTS;
        line_list[i].type = visualization_msgs::Marker::LINE_LIST;
        line_list[i].color.r = 1; line_list[i].color.g = 1; line_list[i].color. b = 1; line_list[i].color.a = 1;
        marker[i].scale.x = 0.003;
        marker[i].scale.y = 0.003;
        marker[i].scale.z = 0.003;
        text_view_facing[i].id = i+8;
        text_view_facing[i].type = visualization_msgs::Marker::TEXT_VIEW_FACING;
        text_view_facing[i].color.b = 1; text_view_facing[i].color.a = 1.0; text_view_facing[i].color.g = 1.0; text_view_facing[i].color.r = 1.0;
        text_view_facing[i].scale.z = 0.015;
    }
    marker[3].scale.x = 0.05;
    marker[3].scale.y = 0.05;
    marker[3].scale.z = 0.05;

    if(frame_index==10) // Saving the point cloud for only one time to find moved object in it
    {
      pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII ("test_pcd.pcd", *cloudB);
    }
    if(frame_index>10) // Reading above point cloud file after saving for once to compare it with newly arriving point clouds
    {
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);

        if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZRGB> ("test_pcd.pcd", *cloud) == -1) //* load the file
        {
            PCL_ERROR ("Couldn't read file test_pcd.pcd \n");
        }
        else {

            srand ((unsigned int) time (NULL));

            // Octree resolution - side length of octree voxels
            double resolution = 0.1;

            // Instantiate octree-based point cloud change detection class
            pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudChangeDetector<pcl::PointXYZRGB> octree (resolution);

            // Add points from cloudA to octree
            octree.setInputCloud (cloud);
            octree.addPointsFromInputCloud ();

            // Switch octree buffers: This resets octree but keeps previous tree structure in memory.
            octree.switchBuffers ();

            // Add points from cloudB to octree
            octree.setInputCloud (cloudB);
            octree.addPointsFromInputCloud ();

            std::vector<int> newPointIdxVector;

            // Get vector of point indices from octree voxels which did not exist in previous buffer
            octree.getPointIndicesFromNewVoxels (newPointIdxVector);

            geometry_msgs::Point p; std_msgs::ColorRGBA c;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < newPointIdxVector.size (); ++i)
            {                        
                p.x = cloudB->points[newPointIdxVector[i]].x;
                p.y = cloudB->points[newPointIdxVector[i]].y;
                p.z = cloudB->points[newPointIdxVector[i]].z;
                c.r = cloudB->points[newPointIdxVector[i]].r/255.0; 
                c.g = cloudB->points[newPointIdxVector[i]].g/255.0; 
                c.b = cloudB->points[newPointIdxVector[i]].b/255.0; 
                c.a = 1;

                //cout<<newPointIdxVector.size()<<"\t"<<p.x<<"\t"<<p.y<<"\t"<<p.z<<endl;   

                if(!isnan(p.x) && !isnan(p.y) && !isnan(p.z)) {

                    marker[3].points.push_back(p);
                    marker[3].colors.push_back(c);
                }
            }
            marker_publisher.publish(marker[3]);

            pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> P;
            thread t[newPointIdxVector.size()];

            for(int p0=0;p0<newPointIdxVector.size();++p0) { // For each voxel in moved object 
                t[p0] = thread(thread_function,cloudB,newPointIdxVector,p0);  
            }   
            for(int p0=0;p0<newPointIdxVector.size();++p0) { // For each voxel in moved object 
                t[p0].join();
                cout<<"joined"<<"\t"<<p0<<"\t"<<x[p0]<<endl;
            }
        } 

    }    


}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init (argc, argv, "training");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("input", 1, cloud_cb);
  marker_publisher = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker> ("visualization_marker",1);

  // Spin
  ros::spin ();
}
```

This task is really important for my algorithm to complete. I need a suggestion how to make this loops run very fast.
In above code the thread_function is the main function where i'm putting the for loops currentely. Is their any way to increase its performance in above code?

Comment: Have You used -O3 compiler Flag ???

Answer (score 0):

OpenMP is the easiest to implement and try. Just add a couple of lines at your CMakeLists.txt, an include and the famous `#pragma omp parallel for` line just before your for loop.

Comment: how many parallel process can be run using openmp? can it run on gpu also?

Comment: There is not much point on running more parallel processes than available threads in your machine. If you don't specify any option, it will use all available cores by default.

Answer (score 0):

Threading itself is not necessarily a guarantee for speed. If your process is mostly linear, there is nothing to be done in parallel. In your case, it looks like you have a loop and each iteration might be able to be done independently in parallel, but because each loop is so small and mostly simple mathematical operations, the overhead for making each item its own thread might not save you much (if any) time. The algorithm itself might need an overhaul (i.e. doing this an entirely different way), but threading could potentially solve your issue if your loop is huge and you can break it into, say, 4 chunks and parallel process the 4 chunks (i.e. one thread does items 0-100, another 101-200, etc). Just be aware that one process might finish before another and if some other process is relying on the completion of the whole set of data, then you'll need to ensure that you're done with all 4 threads before continuing. And if you do any kind of manipulation of the data (i.e. shifting elements, adding, removing) in the parallel processes, then you could end up screwing up a parallel thread. Hope that helps!